# Web.py reload development server while code was changed

Tags: python, web.py

i'm working on web.py project with separated code in different files
- urls.py for urls,
- views.py for controllers,
- server.py for describing my application and it's option.

But i got a big problem - i need to restart my server (python server.py) every time when code was changed.
it makes me crazy.

I've tried 'touch server.py' and all other project files, tried to remove all *.pyc from project but without restart server code not updated.

May be someone knows how to fix this and save time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#developing states:

*web.py also has a few tools to help us with debugging. When running with the built-in webserver, it starts the application in debug mode. In debug mode any changes to code and templates are automatically reloaded and error messages will have more helpful information.*

*The debug is not enabled when the application is run in a real webserver. If you want to disable the debug mode, you can do so by adding the following line before creating your application/templates.*

```
web.config.debug = False
```

Are you using the internal webserver or an external one?